# Spiral path animation using CGMutablePathRef

Tags: ios, core-animation, quartz-2d, cgpath

I'm trying to animate a view from the center of the screen to the upper left corner in a spiral-type motion. Here's what I'm doing:

```
CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, viewOrigin.x, viewOrigin.y);

        controlX1 = viewOrigin.x + halfScreenWidth*0.3;
        controlY1 = viewOrigin.y + halfScreenHeight*0.1;
        controlX2 = viewOrigin.x - halfScreenWidth*0.05;
        controlY2 = viewOrigin.y + halfScreenHeight*0.5;
        controlX3 = viewOrigin.x - halfScreenWidth*0.4;
        controlY3 = viewOrigin.y;

        rndX1 = viewOrigin.x + halfScreenWidth*.1;
        rndX2 = viewOrigin.x - halfScreenWidth*.40;
        rndY1 = viewOrigin.y + halfScreenHeight*.10;
        rndY2 = viewOrigin.y + halfScreenHeight*.35;
    }


    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, controlX1, controlY1, rndX1, rndY1);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, controlX2, controlY2, rndX2, rndY2);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, controlX3, controlY3, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
    CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: pathAnimation, nil]];
    group.duration = 3.0f;
    group.delegate = self;
    [group setValue:self.theView forKey:@"imageViewBeingAnimated"];
```

The view moves to each point on the curve, but it's not smooth, and not very curvy either. It just moves in pretty much a straight line to each point. Why isn't the path curved? I'm using [this](http://blog.shoguniphicus.com/2011/05/19/keyframe-animation-ios-cakeyframeanimation-objective-c/) as a reference.

Comment: What about the rest of the key frame animation?

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant, but I added it above.

Comment: I ran the code you above (but had to fill in some of my own values for endPath, viewOrigin, pathAnimation, theView, etc.). It does follow the path as I would expect it to do. I suggest you set the path to a stroked shape layer to see if the path really is what you think it is. Otherwise you need to provide more information so that others are able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more smooth spiral, you could use the following function. It' s possible to adjust the code to have an opening spiral also.

```
-(void)addEnteringSpiralOnPath: (CGMutablePathRef) path
                          size: (CGSize)size
                         turns: (int)turns
{
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, size.width/2, 0); //To begining: Right

    for (int turn = turns; turn >= 1; turn--) {
        CGSize largeSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * turn/turns, size.height * turn/turns);
        CGSize smallSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * (turn-1) / turns, size.height * (turn-1) / turns);
        NSLog(@"Large: %@; Small: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(largeSize), NSStringFromCGSize(smallSize));

        CGFloat wStep = (largeSize.width/2 - smallSize.width/2 ) / 360;
        CGFloat hStep = (largeSize.height/2 - smallSize.height/2 ) / 360;

        for (CGFloat i = 0; i<=360; i = i + 10) {
            CGFloat iRad = i * M_PI / 180.0f;
            CGPoint p = CGPointMake(cosf(iRad) * (largeSize.width/2 - wStep * i),
                                    sinf(iRad) * (largeSize.height/2 - hStep * i));
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, p.x, p.y);
        }
    }

}
-(void)addOpenningSpiralOnPath: (CGMutablePathRef) path
                          size: (CGSize)size
                         turns: (int)turns
{
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0); //To begining: Center

    for (int turn = 1; turn <= turns; turn++) {
        CGSize largeSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * turn/turns, size.height * turn/turns);
        CGSize smallSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * (turn-1) / turns, size.height * (turn-1) / turns);
        NSLog(@"Large: %@; Small: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(largeSize), NSStringFromCGSize(smallSize));

        CGFloat wStep = (largeSize.width/2 - smallSize.width/2 ) / 360;
        CGFloat hStep = (largeSize.height/2 - smallSize.height/2 ) / 360;

        for (CGFloat i = 0; i<=360; i = i + 10) {
            CGFloat iRad = i * M_PI / 180.0f;
            CGPoint p = CGPointMake(cosf(iRad) * (smallSize.width/2 + wStep * i),
                                    sinf(iRad) * (smallSize.height/2 + hStep * i));
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, p.x, p.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you will just need a simple code like that to make the path:

```
    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();

    [self addEnteringSpiralOnPath:pathToDraw size:CGSizeMake(400, 400) turns:3];
```